# Can't uninstall Dynamic Code Coverage Tools from a agent

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure-devops, sonarqube, code-coverage

I'm trying to unistall Dynamic Code Coverage Tools from my agent but I can't. Should I uninstall from Visual Studio installer? If this is the way, how I can do it? There is no information about this tool.

Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic Coverage Tools can be found in `visual studio installation folder (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Team Tools\Dynamic Code Coverage Tools` ).

You can delete this folder directly. After you delete it. you will get a warning “cannot find codecoverage.exe”,When you run your test with codecoverage enabled.

codecoverage.exe aslo resides in nugget package  `%UserProfile%\.nuget\packages\microsoft.codecoverage`. You can delete this package too.

[image]

Comment: @Dalio141 have you tried above reply? Did it work for you?